# Deleting a very long path in a directory

Tags: windows, ant

I have a pretty weird problem with a folder structure that was created by my ant build...it created a folder structure such that C:helper/class/helper/class/helper/class and goes on for a very long time.

I was wondering if there was some script that I could use to delete these folders using cmd on Windows 7.

I have already tried:

```
rmdir /s /q
```

along with trying to use :

```
robocopy "C:helper/class/helper/class/helper/class" C:Test
```

But still I got no luck...

Does anyone have any suggestions or script that I could use for a bat file to recursively delete this structure?

Comment: Using normal delete process, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover file name is too long....I tried going through each folder and making it an a so it is `a/a/a/a/a/a/a/helper/class/helper/class` but to no avail...I was reading that I should take the intermediary folders and remove them to the desktop and delete the shorter higher structure but it seems like it is taking forever

Comment: All i am asking is if you delete the top root folder, what error do you get. i am assuming you want to delete the whole folder?

Comment: There should be a backslash after the "C:". Also, most Windows commands expect backslashes ("\") as path separators, not forward slashes ("/"). So: `rmdir /s /q C:\helper\class\helper\class\helper\class`

Comment: [This tool by @RickStrahl](http://superuser.com/a/894056/300997) helped me. Whether using robocopy Rick's tool, appending `> NUL` is recommended.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
 robocopy /e /b /purge c:\empty c:\folder-to-delete
```

Comment: It might be a little more useful to explain this. It worked for me, but for the benefit of others who may not have heard of Robocopy.

Comment: Works great, just need to create `c:\empty` first.

Comment: You might as well just go halfway down the directory tree and cut it to C:\ than to use this. All this does is move the folder, you will still have the issue if the folder contents are still too long.

Comment: @KellyBang, the `/purge` option deletes everything inside the target folder, and (when I tested it) worked for paths up to around 8000 characters long.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh of course, it's copying the empty over the folder-to-delete and removing things that no longer exist in the source dir (empty)? I thought it was going the other way. That makes more sense

Answer (score 11):

*del* and *rmdir* commands can't delete folders with long names. But 7-Zip can! Right click on a folder which should be deleted. Select "Add to Archive" in 7-Zip context menu and set "Delete files after compression" option in "Add to Archive" 7-Zip dialog. 7-Zip create archive files and delete folder with long paths! After that you can delete archive file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to a limit on how long paths may be in Windows itself. There's a limit of around 155<sup>1</sup> characters. It's very easy in a Java project (or even a C# .NET project) to create these very long paths. Especially if you're putting your project under something like `C:\Documents and Settings\Baron Van Hushoven\Documents\Projects\My Project` -- 74 characters long).

If this is your issue, you may be forced to use to the [Subst](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726014.aspx) command. This allows you to create a drive letter that represent another path, then you can use that drive letter to help create a shorter path.

```
C:\> subst x: "C:\Documents and Settings\Baron Van Hushoven\Documents\Projects\My Project"
```

Now, you can use `X:` as the root of your project which will shorten the paths you're attempting to delete by 74 characters which may just be enough for Windows to be able to access these files.

---

<sup>1</sup>. The limit is actually 260, but once you put in `C:\`, you're pretty much down to 255. 
Ironically, NTFS can handle extremely long paths of around 32K, and Windows can also handle these long names too. You might be able to prefix the path with `"\\?\" as in`\?\C:\Documents ...` However, I don't believe that works in Windows Explorer or the Command Line Console.

Comment: Robocopy can handle long paths.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Looks like a replacement for `xcopy`. I never heard of it before. Thanks. It's nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have had much more success with the built-in del command in Windows 7.

I have seen `del /s /q` work in situations where `rmdir /s /q` does not.

Comment: Partially worked for me. Deleted 259 char filename, but not 265 char

Answer (score 1):

i've done it with "FastCopy ver3.13"

source : path of to long directory

dest: c:\x\

operation mode (drop down): Delete all (delete all files / dirs by force)

executed it 3 times, and my problem was solved.
robocopy, 7zip does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin and use unix command rm -rf to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I did it programmatically, see the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // This "c:/e" folder contains more then 5000 inner folders with name 'e'.
    // Removing of these folders is slow.
    // It takes about 10 minutes to delete a single tail folder programmatically.
    // But we can arrange these folders to a flat structure with 100 sub-folders depth.
    File root = new File("c:/e");

    // This folder will have parts of the root folder
    File target = new File("c:/e2");
    target.mkdirs();
    int currentFolderNum = 0;

    // Walk to the last folder
    while (root.exists() && root.listFiles() != null && root.listFiles().length > 0) {
        if (root.listFiles().length > 0) {
            root = root.listFiles()[0];
        }
    }

    // Now the root folder is a tail of c:/e/e/...

    int numFolders = 0;
    int nextNumber = 0;
    int partSize = 99;
    while (root.getParentFile().getName().equals("e")) {
        File parentFile = root.getParentFile();
        if (numFolders++ == partSize) {
            File newFolder = new File(target, "f" + ++nextNumber);
            boolean renamed = root.renameTo(newFolder);
            log.info("Count: {}. Folder: {} Moved? {}", currentFolderNum, newFolder.getAbsolutePath(), renamed);
            if (!renamed) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
            numFolders = 0;
        }
        root = parentFile;
        currentFolderNum++;
    }
}
```

Now all folders in the c:/e2 folder have short names and can be removed with TotalCommander or Windows Explorer.